# check common ids in multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes that share common columns.

```
dfs = list(DB07 = data.frame(ID = c("A548480901", "A548480902", "A548480903",
                         "A548480904", "A548560901", "A548560902")), 
           DB08 = data.frame(ID = c("A448440901", "A448440902", "A448680102",
                         "A448680501", "A448680502", "A448680503")))
```

I would like to check if any combination of 2 dataframes have common `ID`s, e.g. are there any `ID` that `DB07$ID` and `DB08$ID` share in common? When I made DB, binding all rows in dfs,
`length(unique(DB$ID))` and `length(DB$ID)` does not match.
I would like a matrix.
if DB07 and DB08 have 0 item in common, it would have '0' as value.

Comment: The data given does not help to answer the question. There is something missing. Please share (parts of) `DB07` and `DB08`. A list of two data frames would be enough to show conceptual approaches.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Do you need all combinations ? Please update your post. There is a `intersect()` function to check for common elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below to find all co-occurrence

```
d <- table(stack(lapply(dfs, unlist)))
d[rowSums(d) > 1, ]
```

which shows (take the data example from [@user2974951's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77779344/12158757))

```
            ind
values       DB07 DB08 DB09
  A448680501    0    1    1
  A448680502    0    1    1
  A448680503    0    1    1
  A548480902    1    1    0
```

---

Or, if you just want to know the **number of co-occurrence**, you can use `table` + `crossprod`

```
> as.dist(crossprod(table(stack(lapply(dfs, unlist)))))
     DB07 DB08
DB08    1
DB09    0    3
```

where you obtain that there are 1 in common between `DB07` and `DB08`, and 3 in common between `DB08` and `DB09`.

Answer (score 3):

You could `unlist()` and then find the `duplicated()` values. Make sure your list has names in the right format to give the name of the data frame separated from the row number by a dot.

```r
ids <- unlist(lapply(dfs, \(x) x$ID))
ids[duplicated(ids)]
#   DB2.1   DB2.2   DB3.2   DB4.4   DB5.7   DB5.8   DB6.4   DB7.1   DB7.4   DB7.5   DB7.6   DB7.7   DB7.8   DB7.9   DB8.2   DB8.4   DB8.7   DB8.9  DB8.10   DB9.8 
#       7      55      51      70      43       7      78      46      55      98      68      12      51      16      82       3      85      52      25      24 
#   DB9.9  DB9.10  DB10.1  DB10.2  DB10.3  DB10.6  DB10.7  DB10.9 DB10.10 
#      12       9      55      75      63      26      48      37      91
```

Note that `duplicated()` only returns `TRUE` from the first time a value is repeated (i.e. the second time it is seen). If you want all times a value is repeated use:

```r
dups <- ids[duplicated(ids) | duplicated(ids, fromLast = TRUE)]
```

Then you can do what you like with these values e.g.

```r
# How many times each value is duplicated
table(dups)
#  3  7  9 12 16 24 25 26 37 43 46 48 51 52 55 63 68 70 75 78 82 85 91 98
#  2  3  2  3  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  2  4  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2

# How many times each data frame contains duplicates
table(gsub("\\..+", "", names(dups)))
#  DB1 DB10  DB2  DB3  DB4  DB5  DB6  DB7  DB8  DB9
#    4    7    7    7    3    4    4    7    5    5
```

Or if you just want a matrix of all overlaps without the values:

```r
df_names <- gsub("\\.$", "", names(dfs))
l <- lapply(names(dfs), \(x) {
    db <- dups[startsWith(names(dups), x)]
    not_db <- dups[!startsWith(names(dups), x)]
    intersects <- not_db[not_db %in% db]
    counts <- table(gsub("\\..+", "", names(intersects)))
    all_counts <- setNames(rep(0, length(dfs)), df_names)
    all_counts[names(counts)] <- counts
    all_counts
}) |>
    matrix(unlist(l), nrow = 10) |>
    `rownames<-`(df_names) |>
    `colnames<-`(df_names) |>
    `diag<-`(NA)

#      DB1 DB2 DB3 DB4 DB5 DB6 DB7 DB8 DB9 DB10
# DB1   NA   2   0   1   1   1   1   0   0    1
# DB2    2  NA   1   0   2   0   3   2   1    1
# DB3    0   1  NA   0   0   0   3   2   0    2
# DB4    1   0   0  NA   0   0   1   0   0    1
# DB5    1   2   0   0  NA   0   0   0   1    1
# DB6    1   0   0   0   0  NA   1   1   1    0
# DB7    1   3   3   1   0   1  NA   0   1    1
# DB8    0   2   2   0   0   1   0  NA   0    0
# DB9    0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0  NA    2
# DB10   1   1   2   1   1   0   1   0   2   NA
```

Or as [@lotus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835261/lotus) suggests in the comments, you can generate this matrix much more elegantly with:

```r
diag<-`(outer(dfs, dfs, Vectorize(\(x, y) length(intersect(x$ID, y$ID)))), NA)
```

#### Data

```r
set.seed(100)
dfs <- lapply(1:10, \(i) data.frame(ID = sample(1:100, 10))) |>
    setNames(sprintf("DB%s.", 1:10))
```

Comment: Thank you. but why would i get 
> ids <- unlist(lapply(dfs, \(x) x$ID))
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `ID`. ?

Comment: looks like you need `ID` instead.

Comment: But I don't want the duplicate within each DB. Instead, I would like to know if two other DBs have common ID

Comment: @D.Shin see my edit for a matrix of counts.

Comment: For the matrix you can do  `\`diag<-\`(outer(dfs, dfs, Vectorize(\(x, y) length(intersect(x$ID, y$ID)))), NA)`.

Comment: @lotus thanks that's much simpler! I knew as I was bolting yet another part to my answer that I would regret it - my fault for diving into answering a question where I was not clear on the expected output. I don't think I'd have come up with that though - I've never used `Vectorize()` in `outer()` like that, that's really nice.

Answer (score 3):

A merge between every possible combination of dfs in a list (I've made up another df to make it more interesting).

```
dfs = list(DB07 = data.frame(ID = c("A548480901", "A548480902", "A548480903",
                                    "A548480904", "A548560901", "A548560902")), 
           DB08 = data.frame(ID = c("A448440901", "A548480902", "A448680102",
                                    "A448680501", "A448680502", "A448680503")),
           DB09 = data.frame(ID = c("A448680504", "A548560908", "A448680507",
                                    "A448680501", "A448680502", "A448680503")))
```

and

```
tmp=combn(seq_along(dfs),2,simplify=F)
setNames(
  lapply(tmp,function(x){merge(dfs[[x[1]]],dfs[[x[2]]])}),
  lapply(tmp,function(x){paste(names(dfs)[x],collapse="-")})
)
```

result

```
$`DB07-DB08`
          ID
1 A548480902

$`DB07-DB09`
[1] ID
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`DB08-DB09`
          ID
1 A448680501
2 A448680502
3 A448680503
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
With the same data as in [SamR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77779120/8245406), slightly edited, the code below first gets all combinations of df's names and then uses those combinations to `intersect` the id's.

```r
set.seed(100)
dfs <- lapply(1:10, \(i) data.frame(ID = sample(1:100, 10))) |>
  setNames(sprintf("DB%02d", 1:10))


nms <- combn(names(dfs), 2L, simplify = FALSE)
common <- lapply(nms, \(x) intersect(dfs[[ x[1L] ]]$ID, dfs[[ x[2L] ]]$ID)) |>
  setNames(sapply(nms, paste, collapse = "_"))

head(common)
#> $DB01_DB02
#> [1] 55  7
#> 
#> $DB01_DB03
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> $DB01_DB04
#> [1] 70
#> 
#> $DB01_DB05
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $DB01_DB06
#> [1] 78
#> 
#> $DB01_DB07
#> [1] 55
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-08</sup>